# What's the Jordan canonical form of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

given is the $6 \times 6$-matrix $A$:

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &0&1&1&-1&0\\ -1&0&0&0&-1&-1 \\ 1 & 0&0&0&1&0 \\ 0&1&0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$

With only the information that

- $A$ has exactly two different eigenvalues
- one eigenvalue is $t_1 = i$

I have to determine the Jordan-matrix.

---

How can I do this with only the information of $t_1 = i$ ?

Comment: The entries are all real, so if there are only 2 eigenvalues, the other must be the complex conjugate of $i$, with a multiplicity of 3.

Comment: Hi - why is this so? Could you please send me some information about this fact, since this really helps a lot! :)

Comment: @DanielV Why must the other eigenvalue be the complex conjugate of the eigenvalue $i$, noting that the entries are real?

Comment: If $Av = \lambda v,$ taking complex conjugates of everything gives $A \overline{v} = \overline{\lambda} \overline{v}$  as $A$ is real.

Comment: Fine question.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem  and the eigen values are the roots of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial which as we can see must have real coefficients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hints.** This is a real matrix. So, nonreal eigenvalues must occur in pairs of conjugates. In general, to answer a question like yours, merely knowing the above fact is not enough. We also need to know the (seldom taught) fact that **Jordan blocks for nonreal eigenvalues also occur in pairs of conjugates**. But fortunately, for your particular $A$, we don't need this latter fact.

Return to the hints. So, the other distinct eigenvalue of $A$ must be $-i$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $A$ must take the form of $[(x-i)(x+i)]^k=(x^2+1)^k$ for some $k\in\{1,2,3\}$. What is the smallest $k$ that makes $(A^2+I)^k$ equal to zero?

Comment: In this case, since $A$ has trace zero, we know that $i$ and $-i$ must occur with equal multiplicity.

Comment: I thank you very much for this necessary information. By knowing that also $-i$ must be an eigenvalue (and both occur with algebraic multiplicity of 3) the solution is obvious. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Supplement** to the above answers.

Let $A$ be a real matrix, then the complex eigenvalues will always occur in complex conjugate pairs.

***Proof***:

If an eigenvalue is complex, its eigenvectors will in general be vectors with complex entries. Now, let $\lambda$ be a complex eigenvalue of $A$, with a non-zero eigenvector $v$, so $Av = \lambda v$. Taking complex conjugates of both sides then yields $$A\bar{v} = \bar{A}\bar{v} = \bar{\lambda}\bar{v},$$
where the first equality follows because $A$ is a real matrix.

So $\bar{\lambda}$ is also necessarily an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$.